# Utilizar facade DB en Tests Laravel

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, test

Necesito utilizar la fachada DB dentro de las pruebas, sin embargo, obtengo el error `A facade root has not been set.`

He intentado cargar la fachada en una extensión de TestCase de la siguiente forma:

```
protected function getPackageAliases($app)
    {
        return [
            'DB' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB'
        ];
    }

    protected function getEnvironmentSetUp($app)
    {
        $app->withFacades();
    }
```

Sin embargo, aún sigo obteniendo el mismo error. Dado la estructura de la aplicación, requiero de la conexión a la base de datos, **utilizar mockery no es una opción.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luego de revisar el código de laravel en más detalle me di cuenta que el TestCase que viene por defecto usaba el trait "`CreatesApplication`", el cual se encarga de inicializar la aplicación.

```
public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }
```

En mis pruebas con el fin de reutilizar un objeto común para todos los tests, estaba sobrescribiendo el constructor, siempre llamando al constructor padre, pero al parecer el lanzamiento de la aplicación está disponible más tarde, por lo cual, utilizar clases que utilicen fachadas en el constructor de una suit de test, dará error para las fachadas.

**La solución**

Remover del constructor elementos que requieran fachadas y llamarlos directamente dentro de cada función de test, para esos entonces, la aplicación y las fachadas estarán disponibles sin inconvenientes.